# convert geoJson data to interactive map tiles containing icons,labels and popups

Tags: geojson, tiles, tracking

In my search for a solution for showing up a tremendous amount of points data on a map, I ended up with an idea of generating GeoJSON data, then convert GeoJSON to **map tiles** that can be served using a tile server.
I saw many sites doing the same but I don't know how.

My questions are :

What tools that can be used on server to generate tiles on fly from GeoJSON data?
The tile must be **interactive, clickable and contain popup messages** and titles for animated points.
Can any expert here give me an idea of how to do this and what is the right way?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is **Vector Tiles**.
For example GeoServer offers this functionality with a plugin.
Look into this tutorial:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html

I think GeoServer doesn't offer GeoJSON as input format yet, but you could load your data into a database, e.g into PostgreSQL. Or just convert it to Shapefile. But as an output it offers GeoJSON also with vector tiles.

Comment: thanks , but what I need is something that can be automated and  integrated to a running website.